# JEST tests failing - fetch is not defined

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I do have two Jest Test Cases which seem to fail but I dont know what is wrong.
It is about Post functions and somehow it doesnt recognize it and gets the error on fetch.

Any ideas appreciated.

**This is what the test outcome says:**

---

● Testing if UI updates correctly › Testing 'updateUI' function...

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'weather' of undefined

      3 |     console.log('all data returned is:')
      4 |     console.log(data)
    > 5 |     const precip = Math.round(data.weather.precip * 10) / 10
        |                                    ^
      6 |     const postHolder = document.getElementById('all-posts')
      7 |     const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
      8 |     newDiv.classList.add('entry-holder');

      at updateUI (src/client/js/updateUI.js:5:36)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__test__/testUpdateUI.test.js:10:12)



 FAIL  __test__/testPostData.test.js
  ● Testing the posting of the data › Test 'postInput' function to make a successful post

    ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

      1 | // POST input data to server
    > 2 | const postInput = async (url = '', data = {}) => {
        |                   ^
      3 |     const response = await fetch(url, {
      4 |       method: 'POST',
      5 |       credentials: 'same-origin',

      at _callee$ (src/client/js/postData.js:2:19)
      at tryCatch (src/client/js/postData.js:10:2404)
      at Generator._invoke (src/client/js/postData.js:10:1964)
      at Generator.next (src/client/js/postData.js:10:3255)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (src/client/js/postData.js:12:103)
      at _next (src/client/js/postData.js:14:194)
      at src/client/js/postData.js:14:364
      at src/client/js/postData.js:14:97
      at postInput (src/client/js/postData.js:2:16)
      at _callee$ (__test__/testPostData.test.js:13:11)
      at tryCatch (__test__/testPostData.test.js:15:2404)
      at Generator._invoke (__test__/testPostData.test.js:15:1964)
      at Generator.next (__test__/testPostData.test.js:15:3255)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (__test__/testPostData.test.js:17:103)
      at _next (__test__/testPostData.test.js:19:194)
      at __test__/testPostData.test.js:19:364
      at Object.<anonymous> (__test__/testPostData.test.js:19:97)
```

---

**And these are the functions:**

```
// POST input data to server
const postInput = async (url = '', data = {}) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    try {
      const newData = await response.json();
      console.log('newData in postInput function is:')
      console.log(newData)
      Client.updateUI(newData)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR in POST:', error);
    }
  }
  
  export { postInput }
```

**And the second one**

```
// Fetches gathered data from server & updates UI with it
function updateUI(data) {
    console.log('all data returned is:')
    console.log(data)
    const precip = Math.round(data.weather.precip * 10) / 10
    const postHolder = document.getElementById('all-posts')
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.classList.add('entry-holder');
    newDiv.innerHTML =`
        <img src="${data.pix.webformatURL}" alt="destination">
        <div class="stat-holder">
            <div class="wait-time"><i>${data.geo.name}, ${Client.checkCountry(data.geo)} is ${Client.dateDiff()} days away.</i></div>
            <h3>Typical weather for then is:</h3>
            <div class="temp">High: ${data.weather.max_temp}&degC, Low: ${data.weather.min_temp}&degC</div>
            <div class="precip">With a chance for ${precip}mm of precipitation</div>
        </div>
    `;
    postHolder.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
  
  export { updateUI }
```

Answer (score 7):

Late answer, but perhaps helps someone passing by this question.

By default, jest runs tests in `Node` environment. Therefore, depending on your packages and configuration, `fetch` may not be available in your tests.

Therefore, the solution is to add `fetch` in the test environment.

### Option 1: mock fetch

Write a mock function in a module, say `mock-fetch.ts`, as follows.

```js
export function mockFetch(data: any) {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      ok: true,
      json: () => data,
    }),
  );
}
```

Then in your test file, you could use it to mock `fetch` as follows.

```js
import { mockFetch } from './mock-fetch';

test('postInput()', async () => {
  window.fetch = mockFetch(someJson);

  // ... your postInput or component render here
  const result = await postInput();

  // Assert your expectations
  expect(result).toEqual(someJson);
});
```

In this approch, you could mock fetch only where necessary. On the other hand, the mock implementation might grow complex if you want to test scenarios like network error or response not ok.

### Option 2: fetch polyfill only in the test environment

Use a library like [cross-fetch](https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch) while running tests.

This approach is as follows:

1. Install `cross-env` as a dev dependency.

```
npm i --save-dev cross-fetch
```

2. Import it in `jest.setup.js|ts`.

```
import 'cross-fetch/polyfill';
```

3. Configure Jest to load it before executing the tests. For example, in `jest.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  injectGlobals: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
};
```

In this approach, you could use [msw](https://github.com/mswjs/msw) to mock API communication as recommended by [testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro#full-example).

### Option 3: use a library like `axios` for the entire app

Use [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) instead of `fetch` in the app.

Then mock the `axios` module using Jest in the test cases.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

test('postInput()', async () => {
  const resp = {data: someJson};
  axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(resp));

  // ... your postInput or component render here
  const result = await postInput();

  // Assert your expectations
  expect(result).toEqual(someJson);
});
```